# c++ recognise if the first parameter in a parameter pack is a pointer assign-compatible with type T

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, smart-pointers

I have only recently started working with variadic templates.

Here is my problem:

I have a function called "`addTo()`" that adds a new object to a collection. The type of the object is the same as the type of the class the function resides in (its a template class). `addTo()` also uses a parameter pack to fill the constructor. `addTo` also recieves a key for the map (thats the collection). Now the collection stores the objects using a `std::shared_ptr`. Now to improve flexibility I want to add the ability to add a existing object to the collection, which will allow me to also add anything thats assignable.

here is an example (pseudo code)

```
class A{
//whatever
~~some function that can be overloaded
A(int,float);
}
class B:public A{
//whatever
~~overloads that function
}
//In some other function
AddToClass<A> instance;
instance.addTo(key,12,2.2); //this is how it already works
instance.addTo(key, new B(12,3.5)); //this is how I also want it to work
```

I dont know if this is achievable or how I can achieve this, however I beg you to explain the (possible) solution in detail since I still have loads of problems understanding parameter packs.

**What I have tried**

- I tried using dynamic cast but I didnt manage to make it so that the
  parameter pack gets expanded (because I don't really get how to use
  them yet other than very basic function forwarding)
- I tried just putting it in the `std::make_shared` call (the constructor) but that doesn't work because I don't want to force the types to have a constructor for each derived class (seems counter intuitive and bad practice)

Please explain to me how to do this (if its possible) in detail. It would really help me out a lot :)

---More info---

Here is an example of how the `addToClass` could look like (pseudo code, written from the top of my head):

```
template<class t>
class addToClass{
private:
    std::map<key, shared_ptr<t>> collection;'
    //sth else
public:
template<typename... Args>
void addTo(const Key &key, Args...args){
   collection.insert(std::pair<key, shared_ptr<t>>(key,std::make_shared<t>(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
//other stuff
}
```

Now everything already works, all I want is that "`addTo()`" can also accept pointers of the type `t` or pointers to some class that derives from `t`. That would allow me to make the function a lot more flexible and save me loads of work in some cases.

Comment: not clear for me; please, can you add more example code? A simplified version of `AddToClass`? The code you've tried?

Comment: @max66 Of cource. Im gonna edit the question

Comment: I understand a little more but still not clear: in your example you declare a `AddClass<int>`; according to following edit, `AddClass` containt a `std::map<Key, std::shared_ptr<int>>`; why do you use an integer and a float to initialize a `std::shared_ptr<int>`? Your intention was `AddToClass<A>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want also that your client class can take pointers, you need SFINAE to disable your additional addTo function.

Full example:

```
class X {};

class A
{
    public:
        A( int, double) {}
        A( X* ){}
};

class B: public A
{
    public:
        using A::A;
};

using Key = int;

template<class t>
class AddToClass
{   
    private:
        std::map<Key, std::shared_ptr<t>> collection;

    public:
        template<typename... Args>
            void addTo(const Key& key, Args...args)
            {
                collection.emplace( key, std::make_shared<t>(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
            }

        template < typename U, typename std::enable_if< std::is_base_of<t, U>::value, U>::type* = nullptr >
            void addTo( const Key &key, U* ptr, X* = 0 )
            {
                collection.emplace( key, ptr );
            }
};

int main()
{
    AddToClass<A> instance;
    Key key = 9;
    instance.addTo(key,12,2.2); //this is how it already works
    instance.addTo(key, new B{12,3.5}); //this is how I also want it to work
    instance.addTo(key, new A{ new X});
    instance.addTo(key, new B{ new X});
    instance.addTo(key, new X);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not seeing this earlier. It works great just now my pointer seems to get invalidated (the pointer adress is correct but after inserting every time I call a member function of that instance the program ends with "program terminate called without active exception"). I dont know if this function is responsible because it wouldnt make much sense if it was so I am gonna tick this. Also I didnt use the X parameter because I didnt see a use for it?

Comment: @MoustacheSpy: The X parameter is only given as example for having pointers related and unrelated and show that sfinea did what it should do. Simply sfinae check in that example that your given pointer is from a class which is derived from the given base class. Not more not less ;) According to your problem with program ends with exception: Is it possible you use the pointer to the object or baseobjt in the constructor itself? That maybe results in havin a vtable which is not initialized.

Comment: the problem was in the way I did the insert function where when there is no entry for key I expect an exception and then put a new one in instead of appending to the list (lots of shit without context). Basically the temporary shared_ptr got destroyed and deleted the pointer. Man I wish I could check if the pointer was deleted somehow.

Comment: @MoustacheSpy: In case of dealing with dangling pointers you should check your design in general. Maybe a shared_ptr can help.

Comment: I am only really using danglin pointers when interacting from the main with the underlying system. Its much more convinient to pass pointers than shared_ptr s since its much easier to do shit like base pointers and assign it. If I have to work with shared in that case its gonna get confusing, however I might add a 3rd option so that I could also pass one down.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your intention was to have a `AddToClass<A>`, not an `AddToClass<int>`.

In this case, I suggest to use `emplace()` instead of `instert()`, write your variadic method as follows

```
  template <typename ... Args>
  void addTo (Key const & key, Args && ... args)
   { collection.emplace(key,
        std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...)); }
```

and add a `addTo()` version for (derived from `T`) pointers

```
  template <typename U>
  void addTo (Key const & key, U * p)
   { collection.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
                        std::forward_as_tuple(key),
                        std::forward_as_tuple(p)); }
```

If you want, you can add a `std::enable_if` to SFINAE enable the last method only if `U` is derived from `T`.

The following is a full working example

```
#include <map>
#include <memory>

struct A
 { A (int, float) {} };

struct B: public A
 { B (int i, float f) : A{i, f} {} };

using Key = int;

template <typename T>
class addToClass
 {
   private:
      std::map<Key, std::shared_ptr<T>> collection;

   public:
      template <typename ... Args>
      void addTo (Key const & key, Args && ... args)
       { collection.emplace(key,
            std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...)); }

      template <typename U>
      void addTo (Key const & key, U * p)
       { collection.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
                            std::forward_as_tuple(key),
                            std::forward_as_tuple(p)); }
 };

int main ()
 {
   addToClass<A> instance;

   instance.addTo(1, 12,2.2);
   instance.addTo(2, new B(12,3.5));
 }
```

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I want! If it wasnt too much trouble, could you do me a favor and explain it a bit more? I am having trouble understanding whats happening. How are you making the compiler differenciate between the two functions? I had a simmillar setup but the compiler always called the one with the parameter pack.

Comment: @MoustacheSpy The template which takes "any pointer" fits better than an argument list which takes everything because a pointer fits better than everything. But as this takes "every pointer" it is not a well solution. In the case you class A or B takes pointers as args you run into the same trouble!

Comment: @Klaus True, but some of my classes might take a cstring or other pointer based variables :/

Comment: @MoustacheSpy: You have seen my answer? Its exactly resolves that problem!

Comment: @Klaus - how explained in my answer, you can use `std::enable_if` to enable the second version of `addTo()` **only** when `U` is derived from `T`; see the Klaus's answer for a practical example.